# Toggling 'Output' window in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Pressing ALT+2 brings up the output pane in Visual Studio 2012, but what is the command to make it disappear again?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the general Window.Hide command (and bind a shortcut to it) to make the output window disappear when it is selected.